# Can EclipseLink cache be removed automatically

Tags: eclipselink

If I am using EclipseLink for entity cache or named query cache with a timeout, I suppose it will not be automatically removed when the cache is timed out in order to save memory. Does it?

If I have a memory problem like Heap memory is at critical level, will EclipseLink cache be automatically removed (does it use WeakReference or similar mechanism to manage cache map instead of strong reference) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink has both an identity map and cache at the factory level, allowing a set cache size and an expensive identity map that allows for garbage collection.  The [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/cache001.htm) explains it and the options available to control or disable it depending on your application needs